# IntelliJ IDEA reloads maven projects each time pom file changed

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I work in IntelliJ IDEA and do even a slightest change in one pom file - IDE triggers lots of background tasks which slows down everything (Reload Maven module, Resolving Maven dependencies, Importing Maven projects, Updating OSGi indices, etc) and it runs for ages. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably caused by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117446, but  perhaps it is caused by another easily fixable problem, you should make a CPU snapshot and report a bug.

Try to hide the Project View to speed things up.

You can disable automatic reloading in: `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing`

Answer (score -1):

This can be avoided- Go to windows->preferences->maven->there you will find the options